# Preventing templates inside <script> tags from being executed in page templates

Tags: cordova, html-framework-7

I'm using page templates in my app to keep things nice and DRY, like {{> navbar}} partials and the like.

I'm trying to avoid putting every single template inside index.html, but positioning them inside the pages they're used in makes it so that when the page is loaded Template7 tries to execute the template inside the  tags and errors out.

Is there something I'm missing or do I actually have to *put every single thing inside my index file*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I just ended up sticking my templates in a directory, one per file, and loading them via AJAX to pass the compiled template to a callback.

```
function loadTemplate(name, callback) {
     $.get('templates/' + name + '.tpl', function(template) {
         callback(Template7.compile(template));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to put everything inside of your index file - In fact, I have almost nothing in there for my apps.

The only stuff you should really have in there is something that you will always need to have shown or be ready to be shown (some type of main container or menu). Everything else that is used sometimes or is just supposed to pop up I create with javascript like so :

```
function createRandomPage() {

    // Main container
    var randomPage = document.createElement('div');
    randomPage.className = "mainPages";
    var randomText = document.createElement('p');
    randomText.className = "mainPagesText";
    randomText.innerText = "Hello I'm a new page";
    randomPage.appendChild(randomText);

    // Destroys page when you move it off of the screen
    // Doing this avoids unnecessary memory usage
    randomPage.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
        if (randomPage.style.animationName == "removeRandomPage") {

            console.log("destroying random page");
            document.body.removeChild(randomPage);
        }
    });

    document.body.appendChild(randomPage);
}
```

Comment: That's not what I meant, sorry. I kind of suck at explaning myself.

Comment: @Hissvard no worries - just update your question with a better explanation of what you're looking for